# Understand Sonarlint with visual studio connected mode.

Tags: c#, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

We are planning to use SonarLint with VS 2015 , and we are having multiple Development branch and respective sonar projects for each Dev branch.

If I use connected mode with in visual studio then for each branch I will need to provide respective sonar projects path.

My question is , If SonarLint connected mode is only fetching rules from server then I can create a common project with rules and I that can be used by sonarLint. In that case I don't need to provide different project details for each development branch.

Comment: There was no question in your post. But yes, SonarLint connected mode is only fetching rules (nuget analyzers) and ruleset files from the server. If you have the same quality profile for all branches than you could use a single SQ project to bind to.

Comment: Thank you ,  @Tamas

Comment: Not sure whether you still have an open question or not.

Comment: Its closed now. @AmauryLevé

Comment: By the way, you don't need to install the SonarLint plugin in Visual Studio at all! you only need two things:

1) The analyzser assemblies of SonarLint. You put these assemblies in a common Lib place and reference them in your projects from the project Rerefrences\Analyzers node.

2) You adjust your ruleset file to include the Sonar rules and reference the file in your projects

and thats it. The SonarLint plugin ist not needed at all! no need to bind to SonarQube server projects.